# ipcMain: event.reply is not a function

Tags: node.js, electron

I've made a simple `Electron` app which uses `ipcMain` and `ipcRenderer`. Here is the code, which makes sense:

***main.js***

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron')
const { spawn, exec } = require('child_process')

let win

function createWindow() {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 800,
      height: 600,
      minWidth: 610,
      minHeight: 470,
      webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
      }
    })

  win.loadFile('index.html')
  win.webContents.openDevTools()
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

ipcMain.on("checkPerl", function(e){
    tryToRun("perl", ["-v"])
        .then(function(){ e.reply("checkPerlReply", true) })
        .catch(function(){ e.reply("checkPerlReply", false) })

})

function tryToRun(cmd, args){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){ 
    // some code 
  })
}
```

***renderer.js***

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

class Chdump {

    checkPerl(){
        this.message("Проверяем Perl...")
        let p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            ipcRenderer.send("checkPerl", true)
            ipcRenderer.on("checkPerlReply", function(event, res){
                if (res) resolve()
                else reject()
            })
        })
        return p
    }

    start(){
        let self = this
        this.checkPerl()
        .then(function(){ console.log("Perl is installed") })
        .catch(function(){ console.log("Perl is not installed") })
    }
}

let app = new Chdump()
app.start()
```

I skipped some code, that is not relevant to the problem. 
This code runs normally when I run it with NodeJS, using `electron .`, but after packaging the app I'm getting the following error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: e.reply is not a function
```

This error referencing to the following string in the main.js:

```
    tryToRun("perl", ["-v"])
        .then(function(){ e.reply("checkPerlReply", true) })
        .catch(function(){ e.reply("checkPerlReply", false) })
```

I've added `console.log(e)` to look at event object and got the following contents:

```
{ preventDefault: [Function: preventDefault],
  sender:
   WebContents {
     webContents: [Circular],
     history:
      [ 'file:///home/kolesnikov/changedump/resources/app/index.html' ],
     currentIndex: 0,
     pendingIndex: -1,
     inPageIndex: -1,
     _events:
      { 'navigation-entry-commited': [Function],
        'ipc-message': [Function],
        'ipc-message-sync': [Function],
        'pepper-context-menu': [Function],
        '-did-get-response-details': [Function],
        '-did-get-redirect-request': [Function],
        'devtools-reload-page': [Function],
        '-new-window': [Function],
        '-web-contents-created': [Function],
        '-add-new-contents': [Function],
        'will-navigate': [Function],
        'did-navigate': [Function],
        destroyed: [Function],
        'devtools-opened': [Function],
        move: [Function],
        activate: [Function],
        'page-title-updated': [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 17,
     _maxListeners: 0,
     browserWindowOptions:
      { width: 800,
        height: 600,
        minWidth: 610,
        minHeight: 470,
        webPreferences: [Object] } } }
```

I tried to do same with non-packaged app, which runs with NodeJS and I got suprisingly different result:

```
{ preventDefault: [Function: preventDefault],
  // [...] looks the same as a previous object
  frameId: 1,
  reply: [Function] }
```

The second `Event` object looks fine, and it has a `reply` property. I'm still didn't understand, why the `electron` Event object has no `reply` property after packaging.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Okay, i solved my problem using the `elecron-packager`. Seems like I did something wrong during manual packaging.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*use e.sender.send in place of e.reply*

```
ipcMain.on("checkPerl", function(e){
    tryToRun("perl", ["-v"])
        .then(function(){ e.sender.send("checkPerlReply", true) })
        .catch(function(){ e.sender.send("checkPerlReply", false) })

})
```

Comment: But, why? When https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-main clearly states: "To send an asynchronous message back to the sender, you can use event.reply(...)."?